# Can't setFont(Times-Roman) missing the T1 files?

Tags: python, odoo, reportlab

I have the error :

`Can't find .pfb for face 'Times-Roman'
Error: reportlab.graphics.renderPM.RenderPMError: Can't setFont(Times-Roman) missing the T1 files?`

I think the Times-Roman fonts is not getting.

Can anyone have a solution for this one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After the R&D i found the solutions for this... and its work for me...

-> This error is also post in [*bugs.debian.org*](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=745985), and patch is provide to avoid this error.

-> And another solution is (*I prefer this one*):

Download this [*pfbfer.zip*](http://www.reportlab.com/ftp/fonts/pfbfer.zip), and extract it.

Now put all the files of this **pfbfer** in...

`/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/reportlab/fonts/(put the files)`

If the **fonts** folder is not available in reportlab directory then create it and put all the font-files in **fonts** from the extract folder **pfbfer**.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling reportlab worked for me.

```
pip3 install --upgrade reportlab
pip3 install rlPyCairo
```