# renderPM Can't find .pfb for face 'Times-Roman'

Tags: python, python-3.x, reportlab

Full error log:

```
Warn: Can't find .pfb for face 'Times-Roman'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lib\site-packages\reportlab\graphics\renderPM.py", line 242, in _setFont
ValueError: _renderPM.gstate_setFont: Can't find font!

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lib\site-packages\reportlab\graphics\renderPM.py", line 248, in _setFont
TypeError: makeT1Font() argument 2 must be str, not None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 69, in run
  File "lib\site-packages\reportlab\graphics\renderPM.py", line 680, in drawToFile
  File "lib\site-packages\reportlab\graphics\renderPM.py", line 666, in drawToPMCanvas
  File "lib\site-packages\reportlab\graphics\renderPM.py", line 51, in draw
  File "lib\site-packages\reportlab\graphics\renderbase.py", line 204, in draw
  File "lib\site-packages\reportlab\graphics\renderPM.py", line 98, in initState
  File "lib\site-packages\reportlab\graphics\renderPM.py", line 92, in applyState
  File "lib\site-packages\reportlab\graphics\renderPM.py", line 399, in setFont
  File "lib\site-packages\reportlab\graphics\renderPM.py", line 251, in _setFont
reportlab.graphics.renderPM.RenderPMError: Can't setFont(Times-Roman) missing the T1 files?
Originally <class 'TypeError'>: makeT1Font() argument 2 must be str, not None
```

I have tried the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28281891/cant-setfonttimes-roman-missing-the-t1-files) but that didn't fix anything.

I have extracted the file into the fonts folder that is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28281891/cant-setfonttimes-roman-missing-the-t1-files), but nothing worked.

I am using a virtual environment if that could be one of the issues.

I have tried adding in a font with `Times-Roman` as the name, but that didn't work as well.

Please note I am on a windows operating system, and this error occurs when I build my application with Pyinstaller.

This is what my directory looks like:

`dxf2png/Lib/site-packages/reportlab/fonts`

```
00readme.txt
bitstream-vera-license.txt
callig15.afm
callig15.pfb
cobo____.pfb
cob_____.pfb
com_____.pfb
coo_____.pfb
DarkGarden-changelog.txt
DarkGarden-copying-gpl.txt
DarkGarden-copying.txt
DarkGarden-readme.txt
DarkGarden.sfd
DarkGardenMK.afm
DarkGardenMK.pfb
sy______.pfb
Vera.ttf
VeraBd.ttf
VeraBI.ttf
VeraIt.ttf
zd______.pfb
zx______.pfb
zy______.pfb
_abi____.pfb
_ab_____.pfb
_ai_____.pfb
_a______.pfb
_ebi____.pfb
_eb_____.pfb
_ei_____.pfb
_er_____.pfb
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved this issue is by reinstalling everything on a different PC... idk if it was really necessary, but it worked and I didn't get any further errors.

(I reinstalled everything on windows 7 and not on 10)

Answer (score 0):

In [this user guide](https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf), you'll find everything you are looking for (especially, pages 48-52).

Basically, you need to include the font description files in the Adobe .afm ('Adobe Font Metrics') and .pfb('Printer Font Binary') format.

So here is the example for the DarkGardenMK, taken from there:

```
import os
import reportlab
folder = os.path.dirname(reportlab.__file__) + os.sep + 'fonts'
afmFile = os.path.join(folder, 'DarkGardenMK.afm')
pfbFile = os.path.join(folder, 'DarkGardenMK.pfb')

from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
justFace = pdfmetrics.EmbeddedType1Face(afmFile, pfbFile)
faceName = 'DarkGardenMK' # pulled from AFM file
pdfmetrics.registerTypeFace(justFace)
justFont = pdfmetrics.Font('DarkGardenMK', faceName, 'WinAnsiEncoding')
pdfmetrics.registerFont(justFont)
canvas.setFont('DarkGardenMK', 32)
canvas.drawString(10, 150, 'This should be in')
canvas.drawString(10, 100, 'DarkGardenMK')
```

So, test that it works - that you can direct to that font and draw it, and if it does do the same for the `Times-Roman` font (with the corresponding .afm, .pfb files).

If that fails, see the explanation for the **TrueType Font Support** on page 51.

Hope it helps!

Comment: after trying this with `Vera` and converting the `ttf` file to `afm` and `pfb` and having them in the same directory in `reportlab/fonts` and using your above code (I did changed everything to `Vera` I still get: `AssertionError: file C:\Users\grossj\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI171082\reportlab\fonts\Vera.pfb not found`

And leaving everything as `DarkGardenMK` I still got the same error, just `DarkGardenMk not found`

Comment: What is the value of the var. "T1SearchPath" in the  reportlab/rl_config.py file? Does it match the fonts path?

Comment: There is no `T1SearchPath` variable in `rl_config.py`.... There is one in `rl_settings.py`.

Comment: Did you set it up? If that didn't work, maybe try to move to the rl_config.py file (based on the documentation, page 8)

Comment: No I didn't set up anything, I don't even use the fonts in my project, the only code in my project that use reportlab are this: `from reportlab.graphics import renderPM` and this: `renderPM.drawToFile(drawing, imgLoc, fmt="PNG")` No where else am I using fonts or anything related to reportlab

Comment: Try setting it up

Comment: how do I do that? Does it show in the documentation? and set up what specifically?